# python tkinter logging -Japanes character Error messages not write in the log file UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, logging

I have two python files

errmessages.py
In that all error messages are mentioned

```
EMPLOYENUMINVALID="従業員番号が無効です"
```

myapp.py

```
import logging
from errmessages  import EMPLOYENUMINVALID

logging.basicConfig(filename="apperror.log",
format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
datefmt='%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S', filemode='a') 
logger=logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

empNum=100
if (empNum <=300):
    logger.error(EMPLOYENUMINVALID)
```

log file is created , nothing is written in the log file .

if mentioned in english like below
EMPLOYENUMINVALID="The employee number is invalid"

log file values written as "The employee number is invalid"

can you anyone help me out

Comment: You should use `logging.error(...)` instead.  `logger` is not necessary.

Comment: That also not working

Comment: It works for me using both `logging.error(...)` and `logger.error(...)`.

Comment: Whether you are using the same two files that I mentioned myapp.py and errmessages.py ?

This is my actual requirement. If you give direct string it will wok always

Comment: Yes, tried using the same two files and works fine.

Comment: For me nothing japanese character is in the log file

Comment: See [my output log file](https://imgur.com/a/lXxUU33).  First line is using `logger.error(...)` and the second line is using `logging.error(...)`.

Comment: for me it shows error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters " not print japanese character in the log file

Comment: Try using `EMPLOYENUMINVALID=u"従業員番号が無効です"` inside `errmessages.py`.

Comment: I tried that also not  working for me
wherther I need to change any system settings ?

Comment: If your Python is 3.9+, try adding `encoding="utf-8"` in `logging.basicConfig(...)`.